# matplotlib: How to use marker size / color as an extra dimension in plots?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am plotting a time series where `x` is a series of **`datetime.datetime`** objects and `y` is a series of doubles.

I'd like to map the marker size to a third series `z` (and possibly also map marker color to a fourth series `w`), which in most cases could be accomplished with:

```
scatter(x, y, s=z, c=w)
```

except **`scatter()`** does not permit `x` being a series of `datetime.datetime` objects.

```
plot(x, y, marker='o', linestyle='None')
```

on the other hand works with `x` being `datetime.datetime` (with properly tick label), but markersize/color can only be set for all points at once, namely no way to map them to extra series.

Seeing that `scatter` and `plot` each can do half of what I need, is there a way to do both?

**UPDATE** following **[@tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell)**'s question, I realized `scatter` raised an `KeyError` deep in the `default_units()` in `matplotlib/dates.py` on the line:

```
x = x[0]
```

and sure enough my `x` and `y` are both Series taken from a pandas DataFrame which has no '0' in index. I then tried two things (both feel somewhat hacky):

First, I tried modify the DataFrame index to `0..len(x)`, which led to a different error inside `matplotlib/axes/_axes.py` at:

```
offsets  = np.dstack((x,y))
```

`dstack` doesn't play nice with pandas Series. So I then tried convert `x` and `y` to numpy.array:

```
scatter(numpy.array(x), numpy.array(y), s=numpy.array(z))
```

This almost worked except scatter seemed to have trouble auto-scaling `x` axis and collapsed everything into a straight line, so I have to reset `xlim` explicitly to see the plot.

All of this is to say that `scatter` could do the job albeit with a bit of convolution. I had always thought matplotlib can take any array-like inputs but apparently that's not quite true if the data is not simple numbers that require some internal gymnastics.

**UPDATE2** I also tried to follow **[@user3666197](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3666197/user3666197)**'s suggestion (thanks for the editing tips btw). If I understood correctly, I first converted `x` into a series of 'matplotlib style days':

```
mx = mPlotDATEs.date2num(list(x))
```

which then allows me to directly call:

```
scatter(mx, y, s=z)
```

then to label axis properly, I call:

```
gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

(call `show()` to update the axis label if interactive mode)

It worked quite nicely and feels to me a more 'proper' way of doing things, so I'm going to accept that as the best answer.

Comment: Can you make an issue for that, scatter _should_ work with the unit frame work.  What error does it raise?

Comment: @tcaswell now that you ask, I went back and noticed that **`scatter`** raised a 'KeyError' which is at least in part due to `x` (and `y`) being a pandas Series. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: *internal **gymnastics*** is a marvelous point :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is there a way to do both? Yes.

However, lets work by example:

[image]
[image]

**step A**: from a `datetime` to a `matplotlib` convention-**compatible** **`float`** for dates/times
**step B**: adding **`3D`** | **`4D`** | **`5D`** capabilities ( using additional { `color` | `size` | `alpha` } --coded dimensionality of information )

---

As usual, **devil** is hidden in detail.

**`matplotlib`** dates are ***almost*** equal, but **not** equal:

```
#  mPlotDATEs.date2num.__doc__
#                  
#     *d* is either a class `datetime` instance or a sequence of datetimes.
#
#     Return value is a floating point number (or sequence of floats)
#     which gives the number of days (fraction part represents hours,
#     minutes, seconds) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, *plus* *one*.
#     The addition of one here is a historical artifact.  Also, note
#     that the Gregorian calendar is assumed; this is not universal
#     practice.  For details, see the module docstring.
```

So, highly recommended to re-use their "own" tool:

```
from matplotlib import dates as mPlotDATEs   # helper functions num2date()
#                                            #              and date2num()
#                                            #              to convert to/from.
```

---

### Managing axis-labels & formatting & scale (min/max) is a separate issue

Nevertheless, matplotlib brings you arms for this part too:

```
from matplotlib.dates   import  DateFormatter,    \
                                AutoDateLocator,   \
                                HourLocator,        \
                                MinuteLocator,       \
                                epoch2num
from matplotlib.ticker  import  ScalarFormatter, FuncFormatter
```

and may for example do:

```
    aPlotAX.set_xlim( x_min, x_MAX )               # X-AXIS LIMITs ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- X-LIMITs

    #lt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(      matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(  secs ) )
    #lt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter( lambda pos, _: time.strftime( "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime( pos ) ) ) )

    aPlotAX.xaxis.set_major_locator(   AutoDateLocator() )

    aPlotAX.xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter( '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' ) )  # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- X-FORMAT

    #--------------------------------------------- # 90-deg x-tick-LABELs

    plt.setp( plt.gca().get_xticklabels(),  rotation            = 90,
                                            horizontalalignment = 'right'
                                            )

    #------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Adding { **`3D`** | **`4D`** | **`5D`** } transcoding

Just to imagine the approach, check this example,
additional dimensionality of information was coded using different tools into  { `color` | `size` | `alpha` }. Whereas { `size` | `alpha` } are scatter-point related, for `color` there are additional tools in `matplotlib` included a set of colouring scaled for various domain-specific or human-eye vision / perception adapted colour-scales. A nice explanation of color-scale / normalisation scaler is presented **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771206/3666197)**

[image]
You may have noticed, that this **`4D`** example still has a constant `alpha` ( unused for 5th DOF in true `5D` dimensionality visualisation )

Answer (score 1):

You can probably convert objects in `x` from `datetime.datertime` to `int` (by representing it in seconds since 1970 epoch)

```
import time

x = [time.mktime(elem.timetuple()) for elem in x]
```

and then pass it to `scatter`

```
scatter(x, y, s=z, c=w)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try a for loop. This is a relatively good option as long as you have not too much data to plot. Below I write a small example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

mass = np.linspace(1,10,100)

for i in xrange(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i],'ko', markersize=mass[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]

In principle you can do the same with the colour.