# how to define colormap with absolute values with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap, absolute-value

I use the following script for plotting:

```
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import math
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cdict1 = {'red':   ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.4, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.7, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'green': ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.1, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':   ((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (0.1, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.4, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
        }

white_blue_red = LinearSegmentedColormap('WhiteBlueRed', cdict1)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=white_blue_red)

x = np.loadtxt('data.dat',
                 unpack=True)

plt.scatter(x[0], x[1], marker='.', s=3, linewidths=0, c=x[3], cmap= \
            plt.get_cmap('WhiteBlueRed')) # plt.cm.bwr  
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

The colormap I have defined uses relative values (0 minimum value of function 1 maximum value). the problem is that I want to use that code for plotting hundreds of different files and I want that each plot has the exact same colormap. Is there the possibility to define colormaps with absolute values? That would solve my problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key in this case is the `norm`, not the colormap.

The colormap defines colors for *already scaled* data.  The `norm` scales the data to a 0-1 range.

By default, a `Normalize` instance will be created that scales between the min and max of the data *or* the `vmin` and `vmax` kwargs, if they are supplied.

However, there are a few different helper functions that may be useful in your case.

If you want a discrete color bar, there's a helper function to generate both a `norm` and a `cmap` for you: `matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors`  It takes a list of values and a list of colors and returns a `BoundaryNorm` instance and a `LinearSegmentedColormap` instance:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

data1 = 3 * np.random.random((10, 10))
data2 = 5 * np.random.random((10, 10))

levels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
colors = ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
cmap, norm = matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
for ax, dat in zip(axes, [data1, data2]):
    im = ax.imshow(dat, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none')
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this creates a discrete colormap.

If we wanted to use a continuous colormap instead, we can either specify the same `vmin` and `vmax` arguments or create our own `Normalize` instance and pass it in as the `norm` argument for all images.

Also, there's a similar function to create a continuous colormap from a list of colors:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

data1 = 3 * np.random.random((10, 10))
data2 = 5 * np.random.random((10, 10))

colors = ['red', 'brown', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('name', colors)
norm = plt.Normalize(0, 5)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
for ax, dat in zip(axes, [data1, data2]):
    im = ax.imshow(dat, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='none')
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image]